# ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

My bluemix securegateway client installed on linux , gives an error as :

[2017-10-03 04:08:05.791] [DEBUG] (Client ID 16583) The Secure Gateway client will fetch its configuration from https://sgmanager.ng.bluemix.net/sgconfig/[masked]
[2017-10-03 04:09:08.882] [ERROR] (Client ID 16583) The response is code: ETIMEDOUT, message: connect

This was working earlier , but suddenly stopped connecting.

Does the client use curl to get to the above configuration url ?

Answer (score 0):

The SG Client doesn't use curl specifically, but it does make an HTTPS request to `sgmanager.ng.bluemix.net` as part of the initial connection process.  Following this request, a second HTTPS request is made to `cap-sg-prd-#.integration.ibmcloud.com:9000` where # is 1-5 depending on the details of your specific gateway.

`ETIMEDOUT` is typically caused by something like a firewall blocking your requests, so you could use something like telnet to confirm your connectivity.  A successful connection should be similar to:

```
telnet sgmanager.ng.bluemix.net 443
Trying 169.54.245.68...
Connected to ng.bluemix.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and

```
telnet cap-sg-prd-1.integration.ibmcloud.com 9000
Trying 169.55.54.176...
Connected to cap-sg-prd-1.integration.ibmcloud.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```